# How to "push" the depth buffer back a little bit in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, matrix

I'm trying to draw an outline of a 3D object by using this method:

1. draw the actual object
2. draw the outlines (GL_LINEs of the polygons), but a bit to the back.

However, using a "translate this a bit to the back" approach doesn't work too well on a 3D environment, because the projection matrix tilts things a little bit.

Is there a way to alter the projection matrix so that it puts things a little bit further down the back? I tried altering the z part of the projection matrix, but only remembered now that the projection matrix don't really work like normal matrices.

I suppose the existence of glDepthTestOffset would solve all of these problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [glPolygonOffset](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/Outline_Mode.aspx) to offset your outlines against the object.